# Ask the user to click on the button

Tags: interface

How to better put this message to the user:

```
All files loaded. 
Click the "analyze for duplicates" button to analyze the files for duplicates.
['analyze for duplicates' button here].
```

Comment: It depends on your user base. Are you designing for power users comfortable with complex apps or the proverbial un-tech savvy "grandmother"?

Comment: it would attract a mix crowd actually - some very tech savvy while others might be more challenged

Answer (score 2):

"Click the button below to analyze the files for duplicates."

and have the button also labeled "Analyze for duplicates".

Comment: better than mine,  as repetition of message down from three times to two times.

Answer (score 1):

I would keep the button disabled at first, until all the files are loaded. Remove the disabled class once it is ready. If your button colors don't make the active / inactive states obvious, try and use some animation

Comment: sorry if i did not make it clear ...buttons only appear after the files have loaded. My problem is that the message to the user is redundant. Notice how analyze for duplicate text appears thrice.

Comment: If you would show the button only after the files are loaded, it would be self-explanatory. This kind of copy seems excessive, especially repeating it thrice.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using this pattern that also has been tested:

"All files loaded, click [here](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/75367/ask-the-user-to-click-on-the-button) to analyze the files for duplicates."

Now you don't necessarily need to repeat a phrase several times, the messaging is shorter, and more obvious for user to click on "here"

Comment: great idea but would be even more fun if I could retain the button some how

Comment: @tao, yeah, that would be good to put that as an alternative, specially if you want to make it responsive. So you can also have a button underneath of this phrase that says: "Analyze Duplication"